# Representations of a symmetry group: what is actually being represented?

Tags: terminology, group-theory, representation-theory, group-representations, lie-algebra

For definiteness, consider the group $SO(3)$. There is a Lie algebra $so(3)$ given by

$$ [T_a, T_b] = if_{abc}T_c $$

The generators of this algebra can be exponentiated to form the elements of $SO(3)$,

$$ \text{exp}[i\alpha_a T_a] \in SO(3) $$

There are various ways to represent the generators $T_a$ in such a way that they still obey the Lie algebra so(3). This in turn yields different representations of the Lie *group*, SO(3).

In this context, it seems that the representations we are talking about are specific realizations of the elements of SO(3) -- that is, 3x3 orthogonal matrices with unit determinant. But then the literature also makes statements like "the fundamental representation of SO(3) is given by the 3 component vector **v**, which transforms under a group element $O \in SO(3)$ via $ v \to Ov$." To my ear they are saying the representation of SO(3) is actually the vector **v**, and not the matrix O.

So my question is: which is it? Are the representations of a symmetry group the generators of that group, the elements of the group itself, or the objects that the group acts upon?

Comment: A little forbearance can get you a long way. A linear map of vectors, or the matrix realizing it, or the logarithmic quiddity thereof can hardly confuse the well-meaning, non-pedantic reader, in any crucial way....

Comment: I think the OP should withdraw it.

Comment: Different people use the word differently. Mathematicians usually say the representation is the map, as @AccidentalFourierTransform pointed out. But usually when you're doing a specific problem, the representation is fixed from the start (i.e. $U(g)$ for a rotation $g \in SO(3)$ is always just physical spatial rotation, you would never consider a different representation $U'(g)$) and we care much much more about how the Hilbert space decomposes. So in this case we talk about representations as vector spaces.

Comment: A representation of a group $G$ is a pair $(V,\rho)$ where $V$ is a vector space and $\rho : G\to GL(V)$ is a group homomorphism. In other words: it is one particular way on which the group can act upon elements of a vector space in a linear way. It is common that sometimes people call $V$ itself the representation, but the homomorphism is actually the important part. See, e.g., the book "Representation Theory: A First Course" by Fulton and Harris.